# where and how to apply a filter in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data called 'theatres'

I have prepared a box plot of all the data with this code:

There is a column in the data called 'sector' and the data within this column is set to either 'Inpatient' or 'Day case'. I'd like to create two boxplots, one with using only the Inpatient rows, and one with only the Day case rows, i thought to use a filter...

Many thanks if you can help a noob with his first ever question.

I have tried to tag this onto the end of the above code but i get an error, i have also tried the filter before each line of code thinking that the hierachy of the code might be a factor (???)

```
   ggplot(data = theatre) +
   (mapping = aes( x = speciality_groups, y = process_time, fill = 
   speciality_groups)) +
   geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Sector", fill = "sector") +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))'
```

trying to use:

```
   filter(theatre, sector == "Inpatient")
```

I get the following er ror:

Error in ggplot(data = theatre) + (mapping = aes(x = speciality_groups,  : 
   non-numeric argument to binary operator
   In addition: Warning message:
   Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"

Comment: think what you want is ```theatre %>% dplyr::filter(sector == "Inpatient") %>% ggplot(data = theatre) +
   (mapping = aes( x = speciality_groups, y = process_time, fill = 
   speciality_groups)) +
   geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Sector", fill = "sector") +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))```

Comment: In other words, use the dplyr package and pipe the result into ggplot. I didn't change your code, just showing the filter first.

Comment: thanks, but i couldn't get 'theatre %>% dplyr::filter(sector == "Inpatient") %>% ' to work, I'm not really sure how the %>% works.

Comment: I don't have your data, but to use a data set provided in R, ```mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(gear == 4)``` works fine. Of course, you have to have the dplyr package installed - it comes with tidyverse, used in the answer provided by @KKW below.

Comment: The operator ```%>%``` is the pipe operator, which was introduced in the magrittr package, but is inherited in dplyr and is used extensively in the tidyverse. You don't need it. There are base R methods to subset your data, but it makes for elegant code once you learn how to use it. Basically, it says, take this data set and send it forward to another operation. The next operation, if it works with the pipe, will use the data sent forward as the first variable, so ggplot gets its data in this way.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your helpful pointers, I'm still very much a beginner and struggling to make some of the suggestions work for me.   I spoke to a colleague and he suggested using this        ggplot(subset(theatre, Sector == "Inpatient"))       and that worked for me.  So what I needed was to subset, rather than filter.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a variable before using ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

theatre_inpatient <- theatre %>%
filter(sector == "Inpatient")

theatre_inpatient_boxplot <- theatre_inpatient %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x = speciality_groups, y = process_time, fill = 
   speciality_groups)) +
   geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Sector", fill = "sector") +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))
```

Then you can do the same thing with "Day case"

The other way is to use facet_grid

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(theatre, aes(x = speciality_groups, y = process_time, fill = 
   speciality_groups)) +
   geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Sector", fill = "sector") +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1)) +
   facet_grid(. ~ sector)
```

Comment: I had hoped to filter without having to create a new data set, any clues?  I have used the 'facet grid' before but there are more than two variables, plus i might wish to filter for other aspects of the data for other plots.

Comment: you can directly use it in ggplot2      ggplot(data = theatre %>% filter(sector == "Inpatient"), aes(x = speciality_groups, y = process_time, fill = 
   speciality_groups)) +
   geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Sector", fill = "sector") +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text (angle =45, hjust =1))